# RethinkDB eqJoin + MAP

Tags: database, join, rethinkdb

i have this problem with RethinkDB.

I have 3 documents:

Person (the account field is an secundary id):

```
{
    "account":  "3580654" , 
    "id":  "356ee84a-8eb5-4b9e-8af5-1cf1ebfe556d" ,
    "name":  "Jesus",
    "lastname":  "Omilon"
}
```

Location (the account field is an secundary id):

```
{
    "account":  "3580654" , 
    "id":  "53d02b06-8fe2-4d48-a8ab-ffd2ff519a32" ,
    "ip":  "127.0.0.1",
    "state":  "21"
}
```

Phones (the account field is an secundary id):

```
{
    "account":  "3580654" , 
    "id":  "692e7e5f-85f2-444f-b6de-a2b1136b80fa" ,
    "phone":  "555-444.44.44",
    "state":  "21"
},
{
    "account":  "3580654" , 
    "id":  "079579aa-ece9-408f-9d00-889a1cb56fc4" ,
    "phone":  "555-432.33.33",
    "state":  "21"
}
```

so i want to join the query to have something like this:

```
{
    "account": "3580654",
    "id": "356ee84a-8eb5-4b9e-8af5-1cf1ebfe556d",
    "name": "Jesus",
    "lastname": "Omilon",
    "state": 21,
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "phones": ["555-444.44.44", "555-432.33.33"]
}
```

Can anyone helpme to do this? i try with eqJoin and map, but without success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: now i have another problem, now i have to order that by Person with phone or exclude records without phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for very detail sample data. That helps answer it easier.

Since `person` and `location` can just be merged to create final location. We can use `eqJoin` to join data.

The `phone` is an array, so we can run a `map` from above result, inside the `map` function, we query extra data of phone table and merge with the main document.

The end query looks like this:

```
r.table('Person').eqJoin('account', r.table('Location'), {index: 'account'}).zip()
  .map(function(doc) {
    return doc.merge({
      'phone': r.table('Phones').getAll(doc('account'), {index: 'account'})('phone').coerceTo('ARRAY')
    })
  })
```

It produces result:

```
{
    "account": "3580654",
    "id": "53d02b06-8fe2-4d48-a8ab-ffd2ff519a32",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "lastname": "Omilon",
    "name": "Jesus",
    "phone": [
        "555-444.44.44",
        "555-432.33.33"
    ],
    "state": "21"
}
```

Note that here we have a conflict of `id` field of `Person` and `Location` when we call `zip()`. So you may tweak query a bit to retain the `id` field that you like

Comment: very glad it helps. Thanks for marking answer and upvote :)